# What is the difference between the Server and Desktop client perspectives?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

Am working to understand basic Lightswitch.

Under DataSources, if I bring up an entity, Desktop shows me a screen that includes a perspective choice of Server and DesktopClient.

What exactly does this mean and when would I select one instead of the other?

Answer (score 0):

The Desktop Client is local to that machine only and if you want it on another machine it must be installed. Whereas the HTML Client is ran on a server and can be accessed via its URL, whether this be on a local network or on a hosted internet server...

so a big difference is when you change the Application, then if running on the Desktop Client each machine would need updating where as on the HTML Client, you as the Host can update the whole application over night lets say without the users having to do anything.. the are many pro's and con's for both but it depends what you want to use your application for. with Lightswitch itself it is possible to use both the Desktop Client and the HTML Client within the same Project.

It depends where your technical skills are aswell as the HTML Client is much more web based,  JavaScript is used a lot more along side C#. The Desktop Client is mainly C# or VB.net... Personally I find the HTML Client easier to use and develop but thats just my opinion :) hope this helps